# Is powerbi file source access based on the running user's computer?

Tags: powerbi

I have an Excel file that is the data source for my PowerBI report.  It's on a network drive that you need credentials to access.  If I specify the path to the file and then upload the report to the Powerbi service, the user should be able to have the report open the file if they have access to the folder?  Even though I don't have access to the folder.

Is it based on the running user's credential when running a report from Powerbi website whether they can load a source excel and not my credential?

Answer (score 0):

Power BI Service will not be able to access your file on the network unless you have Power BI Gateway installed and configured. Easiest/best way would be to have the file in the cloud like SharePoint or OneDrive.

In terms of credentials for data sources, these are set in the Dataset Settings in Power BI Service, under "Data source credentials". The Dataset owner will set these up for each data source, and these credentials are used for the refresh, and not the report user.

See [Data refresh in Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/refresh-data) for more details (section [Accessing cloud data sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/refresh-data#accessing-cloud-data-sources)), also on the same page, information on using Power BI Gateway for onPrem sources.

Comment: any issue with login for different user with sharepoint or set up same way in the data source credential?

Comment: Not sure I understand. The Data Source credential used in the Dataset settings needs to have access/permissions to that source.